# Link toggles when clicked twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my javascript and it works great except that if you click the same link twice it toggles. How can I keep that from happening? Ultimately I just want to show a psection based on item clicked... but if you click it twice it toggles.

```
current = "intersitial"; // div with id="m0" is currently diplayed
function show_or_hide ( id )
{
    if ( current ) //if something is displayed
    {   
        document.getElementById ( current ).style.display = "none";
        if ( current == id ) //if <div> is already diplayed
        {                           
            current = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById ( id ).style.display = "block";
            current = id;
        }
    }
    else //if nothing is displayed
    {
        document.getElementById ( id ).style.display = "block";
        current = id;
    }
}
```

My HTML is:

```
<ul>
     <li onclick="show_or_hide('intersitial')"><span>intersitial</span></li>
     <li onclick="show_or_hide('advancedDetail')"><span>advancedDetail</span></li>
     <li onclick="show_or_hide('ultimateDetail')"><span>ultimateDetail</span></li>
</ul>

<div class="megamenu" id="intersitial">intersitial</div>
<div class="megamenu" id="advancedDetail" style="display: none">advancedDetail</div>
<div class="megamenu" id="ultimateDetail" style="display: none">ultimateDetail</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest changing from the obtrusive JavaScript (using in-line event-handlers, `onclick`, `onfocus`, `onblur` and so on), and instead using JavaScript to bind the events:

```
// use a function-name that's descriptive of what it does:
function showOnly() {
    // or you could use `document.getElementsByClassName('megamenu'):
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div.megamenu'),
        // gets the text from the 'span' of the clicked 'li' (the 'id' for later):
        id = this.firstChild.textContent;
    // iterates over each of the found '.megamenu' elements:
    for (var i = 0, len = divs.length; i < len; i++){
        /* if the id of the current 'div' is the same as the text in the 'span'
           display = block, otherwise display = none:
        */
        divs[i].style.display = divs[i].id === id ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
}

// get the 'li' elements:
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');

// iterate over those elements and bind an event-handler to them:
for (var i = 0, len = lis.length; i < len; i++) {
    lis[i].addEventListener('click', showOnly);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nCQbA/).

This approach also avoids littering the global namespace with variables (which are easily over-written inside of other functions, particularly (but not exclusively) when multiple developers work on the same project).

References:

- [`Element.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FEventTarget.addEventListener).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll).
- [`Node.firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.firstChild).
- [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent).

Answer (score 0):

```
function show_or_hide(id)
{
    if (current == id) return;
    if (current) // if something is displayed
    {   
        document.getElementById ( current ).style.display = "none";
    }  
    document.getElementById ( id ).style.display = "block";
    current = id;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. I see your knowledge is growing fast, unfortunately you can't even upvote my easy effort to help you.